# Написание своего ColorPicker

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Пишу приложение на android для управления LED-лампой и для этого возникла задача сделать Color Picker который будет регулировать теплый и холодный белые цвета.

Для этого у меня есть цветовой круг такого плана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю что проще было бы сделать все в виде полосы, например как в SeekBar, но дизайн приложения требует именно круг =)

Я не очень понимаю как сделать так, чтобы курсор, который будет находится поверх данного круга, не выходил за его пределы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу кусок кода, который на данный момент у меня имеется:

```
    cursor = findViewById(R.id.cursor);

    info = findViewById(R.id.info);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.colorWheel);
    imageView.invalidate();

    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    final Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    float radius = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "width: " + bitmap.getWidth());
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "height: " + bitmap.getHeight());
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreate: radius = " + radius);



    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) v;

            final int evX = (int) event.getX();
            final int evY = (int) event.getY();

            cursor.setTranslationX(evX);
            cursor.setTranslationY(evY);

            info.setText("x: " + evX + "; y: " + evY);
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "x: " + evX + "; y: " + evY);

            img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap imgbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());
            img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            try {
                int pxl = imgbmp.getPixel(evX, evY);

                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Red = " + Color.red(pxl)
                        + "; Green = " + Color.green(pxl) + "; Blue = " + Color.blue(pxl));

                //pickedColorView.setBackgroundColor(pxl);

            } catch (Exception ignore) {

            }
            imgbmp.recycle();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Было бы прекрасно чтобы вы код кинули, раз его нет я приведу пример с `RectF` кругом как это сделать. В `onTouch` отлавливать кординаты x,y клика и если этот x,y в зоне RectF то тогда отрисовывать собственно курсор. В `RectF` есть метод `contains` который способствует этой идее.

Comment: sakuraso13, добавил фрагмент кода.

Comment: вы бы лучше писали это все в отдельном `View`, писать такой код в `Fragment` не правильно. Изучите создание `Custom View`

Comment: А можете поделиться рабочим примером, если у вас есть такой? Когда я погуглил пример, связанный с `RectF` и `contains`, то я не до конца понял, так как это будет связано с прямоугольником а не с кругом.

Comment: С помощью `RectF` можно сделать овал с помощью метода `drawOval()` в классе `View`

Comment: Ну отрисовать то овал не проблема, но а зачем? Ведь задача то стоит в том что бы курсор не выходил за пределы круга, ну а так то получается что, курсор будет находиться в пределах прямоугольника, а не круга. Или я могу в чем то заблуждаться?

Comment: Так вы и будете отрисовывать его только в пределах круга